# iOS plain tableview rows appear behind header

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a plain tableView—one section—and the rows are appearing behind the header when I scroll. Like this: [image]

Is there an easy way to prevent this? I thought it had to do with the contentInset, but that moves the header as well, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a tableview header or a sectionview header? If sectionView header, that's the default behavior. To make an optical illusion, just set the background color of the view for the section header to be that purple color

you have to use:

viewForHeaderInSection and heightForHeaderInSection. Google for examples of these

Comment: okay, yes, it's a section header, so that makes sense. I guess heightForHeaderInSection would allow the scrollview to offset for the header?

Comment: No height for header lets you specify a custom header height for your custom view thats returned from viewForHeaderInSection. Just google for "custom section header uitabletview"

Comment: without heightForHeaderInSection, my first cell was able to be positioned slightly above the section header

Answer (score 1):

When setting `tableView.tableHeaderView` (assuming this is a tableViewHeader and not a section header), make sure you're explicitly setting the height of your `header`.  If you're loading this header from an XIB or Storyboard, the values set in Interface Builder may not carry over to the code.

If this is a section header, you will need to implement the `UITableViewDelegate` method [`tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:).